# Parse textarea line by line (or a specific line #) with Django

Tags: django

I would like to parse the content of a textarea in my django view, line by line (or get a specific line number).
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `text_area_value.splitlines()` instead. Then you don't have to worry about `\r\n` or `\n` issues. Also, it reads better.

Comment: which module is text_area_value located in?

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in text_area_value.split('\n'):
    # do something with line
```

or if you want a specific number (3 in this example - which is the 4th line, counting the "human" way):

```
lines = text_area_value.split('\n')
    # do something with lines[3]
```